# How to Set Updated Base Price with Shipping Charges in Magento 2.4?

Tags: php, magento2

I am currently using Magento 2.4

When I click on "Buy Now". At that Popup occurs and Another addons asking. After I select addons. I updated price using below code :

```
      $newCalcualtionPrice = $baseprice+$addonstotal;
      $product->setPrice($newCalcualtionPrice);
```

After that I can see my updated price in View Cart page.
Then I will click on "Process to Checkout".Also On Step 1. ""Shipping Information " I am able to see updated Cart Value.

But When I am select Shipping method. Like Fixed Charges. And Click on "NEXT". Then Review & payment step. I am not able to get updated Cart Value. I am getting "Original Product Price + Shipping Charges".
But... I want "Updated Cart Value + Shippinh Charges" .
So Can anyone help me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$product->setPrice($newCalcualtionPrice);
$product->save();
```

I suggest you try this